# What is this .Net Obfuscator?

Tags: obfuscation, deobfuscation, .net, c#, de4dot

I'm analysing a .Net executable and de4dot doesn't detect its obfuscator. Class/Method/Property names start with `#=`. Does anybody know what obfuscator this is?

```csharp
// Token: 0x0600EE8B RID: 61067 RVA: 0x005FD1D0 File Offset: 0x005FB3D0
private static void #=zYty0Ku8H9q$P(string #=zndQNTVv$9cLKMhwNUA==)
{
    object[] array = new object[] { #=zndQNTVv$9cLKMhwNUA== };
    #=zJUlsCmxPFKvbh0EyDbcW8B0CcRW$RAie2y9$FflzHIPGQDaemg==.#=z6Kgg5g$lVS73p5E8js4ejGWKF9p9S1pkoyFDU456Zy7P4uBwAw==().#=zTHv$7gizw9KfR6H2XIF19QgccLki(#=zJUlsCmxPFKvbh0EyDbcW8B0CcRW$RAie2y9$FflzHIPGQDaemg==.#=z2vAU$2yunFLLek5WBUt1VZpwwpO21O3R5mIYq4yVvMu5NZwZzQ==(), "qYP%'\"TSDu", array);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check with PEiD? or Yara? Also I think you can load other signatures on DiE (the one you are using)

Comment: please do not post  pictures of text ... post the text instead ... format as code ... use the edit button to update your post

Comment: @jsotola Updated my question with a code sample